# Jenkins Upgrade: What configuration should I be concerned about in the Jenkins WAR directory?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to automate Jenkins Upgrades so they do not have to be hands on. Some documentation recommends creating a batch file with instructions on the machine running Jenkins, and create a scheduled task to run the batch job. The site I found with a batch file is [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade), where it says:

> It does delete the complete exploded war file from the deployment location, so be careful if you save any configuration files to that directory.

What configuration file would I have to worry about? No one I've talked to at my company knows of any configuration files held there, and they seem to think we have a pretty default setup, so what could I look for manually that would tell me whether or not I should be concerned?

We are running Jenkins on a Windows virtual box, I believe with Jenkins running as a service.

Alternatively, if the above method is not the easiest or best way to automate Jenkins upgrades, does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can ignore this warning**. I've never seen anything storing configuration files in that directory. It is intended to be used as a **cache** only.

If unsure, **check your existing `war` directory for any files with timestamps newer than the installation time**.

Here, on a busy Jenkins master, no files have been added or modified there over a period of several months (since initial war file explosion at installation time).

Comment: Good thought on checking the modification time. I'll try that before I run it.